# Spark 2.0.0 application do not auto stop when exception occure on yarn-client model

Tags: apache-spark, client, hadoop-yarn

I run my Spark App on yarn-client model, the spark-submit is like this:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 256 --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 10G --class sparkapps.SparkApp1 /home/hadoop/SparkSBT-assembly-1.0.jar 20150805 256 s3path
```

and my program is like this:

```
object SparkApp1 {

  //  val YAML = SparkApp1.getClass.getResourceAsStream("/regexes.yaml")
  //  val ipdb = SparkApp1.getClass.getResourceAsStream("/ipdb.csv")

  case class RTBRow(receiveTime: String, tag: String, jsonData: String)

  val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.CHINA)

  //  val p = Parser.create(YAML)

  //  val ipfinder = new IPDB(ipdb)

  def sparkJob() = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("HiveFromSpark")
      .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .config("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead", "2048m")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    import spark.sql

    val lines = spark.read.textFile(s"s3:...$date/*")
    val rtbRows = lines.map(_.split("\t", 3)).map(l => RTBRow(l(0), l(1), l(2))).repartition(1024).toDF()
    val retValue = rtbRows
      .select($"receiveTime", $"tag",
        get_json_object($"jsonData", "$.req.device").alias("device"),
        get_json_object($"jsonData", "$.req.imp").alias("imp"),
        get_json_object($"jsonData", "$.req.app.content.keywords").alias("app_keywords"),
        get_json_object($"jsonData", "$.req.app.content.ext").alias("app_ext"),
        get_json_object($"jsonData", "$.req.app.content.title").alias("app_title"),
        get_json_object($"jsonData", "$.req.app.name").alias("app_name"),
        get_json_object($"jsonData", "$.req.iploc").alias("iploc"))
      .select($"receiveTime", $"tag", json_tuple($"device", "didmd5", "os", "osv", "ua", "ip").as(Array("didmd5", "os", "osv", "ua", "ip")),
        get_json_object($"imp", "$[0].tagid").alias("tagid"), $"app_keywords",
        get_json_object($"app_ext", "$.cs").alias("cs"), get_json_object($"app_ext", "$.s").alias("s"), get_json_object($"app_ext", "$.vid").alias("vid"),
        get_json_object($"app_ext", "$.channel").alias("channel"), $"app_title", $"app_name", $"iploc")
      .filter(l => !l.anyNull).na.fill("", Seq("iploc")).rdd
      .map {
        case Row(receiveTime: String, tag: String, didmd5: String, os: String, osv: String, ua: String, ip: String, tagid: String,
        app_keywords: String, cs: String, s: String, vid: String, channel: String, app_title: String, app_name: String, iploc: String) =>
          //        val timestmp = new Timestamp(format.parse(receiveTime.replace("T", " ").reverse.replaceFirst(":", "").reverse.replace("+", " +")).getTime)

          val uas = ua.split(";")
          val locArray = iploc.split("\t").slice(0, 2)
          var province = ""
          var city = ""
          if (locArray.length == 2) {
            province = locArray(0)
            city = locArray(1)
          } else if (locArray.length == 1) {
            val province = locArray(0)
            val city = ""
          }
          ((didmd5, os, uas(uas.length - 1), province, city), (app_name, app_keywords))
      }
      .groupByKey(numPartitions = 1024)
      .map { l =>
        val app_names = l._2.map(p => p._1).toSeq.distinct.slice(0, 10).mkString("|")
        val keywords = l._2.map(p => p._2).flatMap(_.split("\\|")).toSeq.distinct.slice(0, 10).mkString("|")
        Array(l._1._1, l._1._2, l._1._3, l._1._4, l._1._5, app_names, keywords).mkString("\001")
      }

    //
    retValue.repartition(part).saveAsTextFile(output_path)
    //    retValue.take(1000).foreach(println)
    spark.stop()
  }

  var date = 20160710
  var part = 64
  var output_path = ""

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length == 0)
      sparkJob()
    else {
      args match {
        case Array(d: String, p: String, o: String) => this.date = d.toInt; this.part = p.toInt; this.output_path = o; sparkJob()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The program is not very complex，and I do not forget the spark.stop() method. At beginning, even all step are completed, this program do not stop, because i forgot the stop() method. But now, when Exception occure, such as "output path already exist", or "type miss match", error messages can print to screen without app auto stop. I google and search stackoverflow, but no one have the same problem, any on has some idea about this problem?